# Android ListActivity compile error

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am quite new to java android programming and I have a problem that may be quite easy to answer, but I can't figure what the eclipse compile error message implies.

The class runs fine except if I remove the block comment in the **onContextItemSelected** code below, I get this compile error:

**The method onContextItemSelected(MenuItem) of type new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method**

What am I doing wrong or is missing here? Thanks.

**Code**

```
public class ListTest<registerForContextMenu> extends ListActivity  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values));
        listView = getListView();

        // I populate the list view here

        listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.context_menu_options);
                menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.context_menu_reply);
                menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.context_menu_delete);
                menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.context_menu_cancel);
            };

            /*
            @Override
            public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                int index = info.position;
                return true;
            };
            */                      
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `onContextItemSelected` is not a method of `OnCreateContextMenuListener`. That means that you cannot override it.

`onContextItemSelected` is a method of `Activity`. Override it in your `Activity`.

Comment: My class extends ListActivity, how do I do that?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll find that ListActivity extends Activity, hence it works too.

Comment: what is possible? i don't understand your question

Comment: ListActivity is an activity. Your ListTest is a ListActivity. Inheritance is transitive. ListText is an Activity. onContextItemSelected is a method of Activity. you can override onContextItemSelected in ListTest. (but not in the new OnCreateContextMenuListener, which is not an Activity).

Comment: Yes I have moved the block of code outside the listener but I still get the compile error.

Comment: put the onContextItemSelected method in the body of ListTest rather than in the body of the anonymous OnCreateContextMenuListener.

Comment: Post what you have changed.

Comment: Yes, sorry njzk2, you are correct, I messed up by not placing it in the correct location within the class, thanks for the help, much appreciated.